# Is there a reason Google Play Services (> r29) won't work with Eclipse?

Tags: android, eclipse, google-play-services

I understand beyond r29, Google has simply broken down Google Play Services into multiple libraries.

I kind of wonder why does this makes it impossible for it to be used with Eclipse?

Comment: What would you like Eclipse to do with Google Play services?

Comment: You should really look into switching to Android Studio. The ADT plug-in is deprecated since june 2015. https://developer.android.com/studio/tools/sdk/eclipse-adt.html#notes

Comment: @greenapps I want it for google maps.

Comment: @Rockney I actually started on android studio. But its too heavy and bloated for my computer so I had to switched to eclipse. That was 3 months ago, I doubt its improved much since.